# JQuery Mobile Page Not Refreshing

Tags: jquery-mobile, page-refresh

I Did do my home work but i cannot get it to work.***The Button Styles Are Not Refreshing*** Please Help.

```
        <div id="qpage" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a id="exit-quiz" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" >Exit</a>
            <h1 id="ques-title">#ques-title</h1></div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="ui-bar-a" id="ques-timer">
                #ques-timer
            </div>
            <div id="question"><h3>#Question</h3></div>
            <div class=".button-set" data-role="controlgroup" id="answerbox">
                <a data-role="button" id="answer_1">#answer_1</a>
                <a data-role="button" id="answer_2">#answer_2</a>
                <a data-role="button" id="answer_3">#answer_3</a>
                <a data-role="button" id="answer_4">#answer_4</a>
            </div>
            <div id="explanation">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer"><h2>Copyright Kaveen</h2></div>
    </div>
```

This is Th Javascript I wrote

```
            $("#subject1").bind('click',function(){
            var json = $.get("test.json",function(data){
                $("#question").html(data.question);
                $("#answer_1").html(data.mcq_1);
                $("#answer_2").html(data.mcq_2);
                $("#answer_3").html(data.mcq_3);
                $("#answer_4").html(data.mcq_4);
            });
```

i did try `$( "div[data-role=page]" ).page( "destroy" ).page();` But it wont work Plese Help Me Thank you. **JSFIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/xRTCu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should work:

```
$("#answer_1").button("refresh");
```

If that is also not working, try this

```
$("#answer_1").buttonMarkup();
```

EDIT: jsfiddle updated http://jsfiddle.net/androdify/xRTCu/4/
Use this:

```
 $("#answer_1 .ui-btn-text").text(data.mcq_1);
```

Why? Because jquery mobile adds a span around the button which has `class="ui-btn-text"`

Comment: I tryed but not working im now stressed off with this where should this code excecute when the page is there

Comment: Thank you so much.More people like you can make the world a better Place.

Comment: @KaveenR In addition to marking the answer as accepted, you can upvote it too. Also, upvote other answers if they helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `$( "div[data-role=page]" ).trigger ("create")` if you're using the latest version of jQuery mobile. `page` was deprecated some versions ago.

If you're using an older version of jQM, then you could use `$("[data-role=button]").button().button ("refresh")` after you're done appending your JSON data into those buttons.

**EDIT**

From your fiddle I can see that you're using `html()` and that's erasing jQM's markup. This is what `data-role=button` converts your markup:

```
<a data-role="button" id="answer_1">#answer_1</a>

//becomes

<a data-role="button" id="answer_1" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-first-child ui-btn-up-c">
  <span class="ui-btn-inner">
       <span class="ui-btn-text">mcq wrong</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

So by using `html()` youre effectively erasing everything inside `a`. Try searching for `ui-btn-text` class inside `a` like this and then run `html` with your text in it:

```
$(".ui-btn-text", "#answer_1").html(data.mcq_1);
//OR
$("#answer_1").find(".ui-btn-text").html(data.mcq_1);
```

Here's your updated demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/xRTCu/3/

Comment: Thank you so much.More people like you can make the world a better Place.